# How can I pass rails data to javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have a Rails 4 application. I want to display locations on google maps street view. Longitude and latitude are saved in database, so it can only accessed through rails. 
Controller :

```
@posts.each do |post|
  markers << post.marker_single_show
end
```

Javascript :

```
function addMarker(latLng, map, icon) {
  if (formMarker !== undefined) {
    formMarker.setMap(null);
  }
  formMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
    title: "localisation",
    icon: icon
  });
  formMarker.setMap(map);
  var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  latlngbounds.extend(latLng);
  map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);
  map.panToBounds(latlngbounds);
}
```

As you can notice, when using addMarker function I should provide latlng value which is rendred by rails controller.
How can I pass values from rails to Javascript?

Comment: Giving a code example would be more helpful. Depending on how your front end is setup, you maybe could pass in an instance variable setup in your controller, then pass that to the google maps API through something like an onclick function. I know there are also gems out there that help to pass the data to JS (do a similar google search to your question). Also, there are methods of passing back json in the controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
     app/controllers/some_controller.rb
     def someMethod
      @railsVariable = Model.all or Model.find(id)
      end
     in its view you can do something like this

<script>
  var JavascriptVariable = <%= @railsVariable %>;
</script>
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: For those who comes with same question, I used the hack suggested by @ashwintastic and it works well.